# how to check whether you need to parse or not need to parse?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing, d3.js

I have a JSON:

```
var datat= {"Model": "Model A",
                "Datase": [
                    {
                        "Id": "DatchikSveta11",
                        "Group": 2,
                        "State": "on",
                        "Data": [{
                            "Date":"2017-08-11 15:10:34.363",
                            "Value":"0" 
                        },{
                            "Date":"2017-08-12 21:12:34.363",
                            "Value":"32"
                        },{
                            "Date":"2017-08-15 21:55:34.363",
                            "Value":"200"
                            }],
                        "DataVolume": "luxs"    
                    },{
                        "Id": "DatchikSveta2",
                        "Group": 2,
                        "State": "on",
                        "Data": [{
                            "Date":"2017-08-11 17:11:34.363",
                            "Value":"100"
                        },{
                            "Date":"2017-08-15 18:11:34.363",
                            "Value":"100"
                        },{
                            "Date":"2017-08-16 19:12:34.363",
                            "Value":"200"
                        }],
                        "DataVolume": "luxs"
                    }
                ]}
```

I have a function that parse JSON object.

```
parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L");
datat.Datase.forEach(function (kv) {
        kv.Data.forEach(function (d) {
            parseDate(d.Date);
            parseInt(d.Value);
        });
    });
```

This function change values in original JSON object (date to parse date), so when im trying to call this function second time it gives a bad values, because it trying to parse already parsed dates.

**I need to specify a condition that would allow to check whether you need to parse or not need to parse.**
Or maybe someone have a function with the help of which it is possible to extract the parsed value without changing it in an original JSON? I understand that the easiest way is to return new variable from function like:

```
 .data(function (d){
        var a = d.Data.slice(d.Data.length-1,d.Data.length);
        a.forEach(function (k){k["Id"]=d.Id;  k["Date"]=parseDate(d.Date);});
        return a;
    })
```

I can change date format in JSON, but who needs simple way?

Im a new in javascript and have no time for the theory :P 
But i hope that someone can give me a good answer.

Sorry for my english and sorry for the theory, and thank you for attention :)

Comment: I started editing your question but, at the middle of it, I gave up. It's quite unclear. Please, take your time and edit it, clarifying your issue and the desired outcome.

Comment: Agreed, this is very unclear.

Comment: Sorry guys. My english is so bad so It is difficult to formulate an idea accurately.

Comment: Please specify your expected output.

Comment: Check it out now. I think i do

Comment: You can check whether the variable is an `instanceof Date` object. e.g: `x = new Date(); x instanceof Date //true`.

Hopefully this helps because your question isn't very clear

Comment: Thanks for the help! It takes time to try :)

Comment: @Bwaxxlo you are absolutly right! Please modify your comment as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Bwaxxlo said:

> You can check whether the variable is an instanceof Date object. e.g: x = new Date(); x instanceof Date //true.

As D3 API said about d3.timeParse function:

> The returned function parses a specified string, returning the corresponding date or null if the string could not be parsed according to this format’s specifier

So it works clear. And i can do something like this:

```
var jdates =[];
    var jvalues =[];
    datat.Datase.forEach(function (kv) {
        kv.Data.forEach(function (d) {
            if (!(d.Date instanceof Date)){
                jdates.push(d.Date = parseDate(d.Date));
                jvalues.push(d.Value = parseInt(d.Value));
            } else {
                jdates.push(d.Date);
                jvalues.push(d.Value);
            } 
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind adding to the information then you can just throw in a `isParsed` value and check that value. Using your `datat` variable from above you can simply do your changes as such:

```
datat.Datase.forEach(function (kv) {
    kv.Data.forEach(function (d) {
        if(d.isParsed != true ){
            d.Date = parseDate(d.Date);
            d.Value = parseInt(d.Value);
            d.isParsed = true;
        }
    });
});
```

This will run through and make the changes you needed but set a key of `isParsed` and sets it to `true` when you have iterated over it. The forEach with then check if it has been parsed and skip it if it has, otherwise it will parse it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Its a good solution, but I would like to achieve the result without increasing the size of the original json. I would like to find a solution that would allow me to compare the value with a certain template (eg "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L")